# Confusion when dealing with files

Tags: c, string, file, format

I'm writing a program that takes a string from one file, a string from another file and writes them to a third file in separate columns. I really have two questions, If I use fgets to get the string from the files and it stops at the end of the line. Will it automatically know to start from the next line for the next string. Also, how can I format the input to make two columns. An example would be...

first string is "John" from the first file.
second string is "Appleseed" from the second file.

third file would have in it "John______________________Appleseed"
The second line of the third file would have  "Benny__________________________                      Backburner"

Just to format columns.

Comment: 1) Reading from the file is read from the continuation. 2) `printf("%s___%s\n", stringOfFirstFile, stringOfSecondFile);` or `printf("%s%s%s\n", stringOfFirstFile, betweenString,stringOfSecondFile);` or such as.

Comment: I can use regular printf to print to a different file?

Comment: Ah! my bad. Use `fprintf` instead of `printf` like `fprintf(fp, "%s%s%s",`

Comment: And the paraneters you put into the fprintf function would be the buffer arrays holding the string values I pull?

Comment: It is the same as `printf` except that the file pointer is added as the first argument in `fprintf`.

Comment: @DemarcusSales: It is not clear what your problem is. Looks more like lack of basics for streams and functions. This is explained in every good C book. We are not a tutoring site.

Comment: tbh i'm not even really asking for help, just tips.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want underscores, or will spaces suffice?  It's much simpler with spaces. You can read the specification of [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html)
to see the details of what the format strings do.

```
while (fgets(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), fp1) != 0 &&
       fgets(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), fp2) != 0)
{
    buffer1[strcspn(buffer1, "\n")] = '\0';
    buffer2[strcspn(buffer2, "\n")] = '\0';
    fprintf(fp3, "%-25s   %s\n", buffer1, buffer2);
}
```

This reads one line from each of the first two files, removes the newlines from the buffer, and then formats them with the first column left-justified in a width of 25, and the second printed after 3 spaces.

If you must use underscores instead of spaces, then you need something like this:

```
char uscore[256];
memset(uscore, '_', sizeof(uscore)-1);
uscore[sizeof(uscore)-1] = '\0';

while (fgets(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), fp1) != 0 &&
       fgets(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), fp2) != 0)
{
    buffer1[strcspn(buffer1, "\n")] = '\0';
    buffer2[strcspn(buffer2, "\n")] = '\0';
    int len1 = max(0, 25 - strlen(buffer1));
    fprintf(fp3, "%s%*.*s%s\n", buffer1, len1, len1, uscore, buffer2);
}
```

Putting this together, illustrating both techniques at once:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s infile-1 infile-2 outfile\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    FILE *fp1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE *fp2 = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    FILE *fp3 = fopen(argv[3], "w");
    if (fp1 == 0 || fp2 == 0 || fp3 == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: failed to open one of the files %s, %s or %s\n",
                argv[0], argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);
        return 1;
    }

    char uscore[256];
    memset(uscore, '_', sizeof(uscore)-1);
    uscore[sizeof(uscore)-1] = '\0';
    char buffer1[1024];
    char buffer2[1024];

    while (fgets(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1), fp1) != 0 &&
           fgets(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2), fp2) != 0)
    {
        buffer1[strcspn(buffer1, "\n")] = '\0';
        buffer2[strcspn(buffer2, "\n")] = '\0';
        fprintf(fp3, "%-25s   %s\n", buffer1, buffer2);

        int len1 = strlen(buffer1);
        if (len1 < 28)
            len1 = 28 - len1;
        else
            len1 = 0;
        fprintf(fp3, "%s%*.*s%s\n", buffer1, len1, len1, uscore, buffer2);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample input file `data.1`:

```
California
Esoteric
Mismatch
Unexpected
Non-sequitur
Extra-long word list from file 1
```

Sample input file `data.2`:

```
Drought
Persecution
Preliminary
Adequate
Pusillanimous
Rather long word from file.2 too
```

Example output:

```
California                  Drought
California__________________Drought
Esoteric                    Persecution
Esoteric____________________Persecution
Mismatch                    Preliminary
Mismatch____________________Preliminary
Unexpected                  Adequate
Unexpected__________________Adequate
Non-sequitur                Pusillanimous
Non-sequitur________________Pusillanimous
Extra-long word list from file 1   Rather long word from file.2 too
Extra-long word list from file 1Rather long word from file.2 too
```

There are endless tweaks you can make depending on a more precise definition of the format you want.  Amongst other things, you can make sure there's a minimum of 3 underscores between the first and second words in the 'must have underscores' example.  You could limit the lengths of the strings that are printed.

The code should check that it gets a newline within the first 1023 bytes; it doesn't.

Comment: spaces are actually exactly what I needed. So when I use fgets it puts the new line into the array.

Comment: If there's enough space in the array, then `fgets()` includes the newline.  If there isn't enough space, `fgets()` stops reading and null-terminates the string it has got, leaving the rest of the line to be read by the next call (or calls).

Comment: I looked at editing the presentation of your requirements but I couldn't decide exactly what you wanted as the numbers of underscores weren't consistent.  Maybe you should show the output as you want it by putting the two lines of data on adjacent lines, and then indenting them each by four spaces to convert them into 'code'.  The icing on the cake would add separate line (blank line above and below and no indentation) that said `<!-- language: lang-none -->` to prevent them being treated as code and highlighted.  (You can flag this as 'no longer needed' after you've made that edit.)

Answer (score 0):

> If I use fgets to get the string from the files and it stops at the end of the line. Will it automatically know to start from the next line for the next string.

If the line can be completely stored in the buffer then **Yes, it will** (see below for further explanation).

However, there is not really something like lines in the data read from the file. It is more like a continuous stream of bytes. If you have a file in your editor that looks like:

```
a
b
c
```

the data that `fgets` see is like more like this byte stream:

```
a\nb\nc\n
```

The first call to `fgets` will read the `a` and the `\n` leaving the remaining input as

```
b\nc\n
```

The next call to `fgets` will read the `b` and the `\n` and thereby it works as if it starts from the "next line" but it really just continues from where the last call stopped.

Also notice what happens if the line is longer than your buffer. If the file is

```
abcd
efgh
```

and you do

```
fgets(buffer, 3, f)
```

then the first call to `fgets` will give `ab\0` and the next call will continue reading `cd\0`.

In other words - if the line is too long to be completely stored in the buffer, `fgets` will **not** continue from "the next line". If you always want to continue from the next line, you must add code to read from the file until you read a `\n`

> Also, how can I format the input to make two columns.

Well, your question doesn't include sufficient details to come up with exact code, e.g. what should be the spacing between columns, what to do if the input is larger than the spacing, etc.

In any case - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45295262/4386427 (by Jonathan Leffler) which give you some good hints.